# Performance Issues in Celery

Tags: python, celery

I already read other posts about that but none of them solve my problem. I have function to scan all ports for a given ip. It takes 5-10 seconds to complete without celery but if I use the celery to run this function, it takes approximately 15 minutes. I observed that function without celery, consuming approximately %90 cpu power but with celery this value is %2-%3 so task takes 15 minutes to finish. This causes a serious performance problem for me. How to increase a cpu power for a specific task or any idea to solve this problem?

```
@app.task
def port_scan(ip): ##requires nmap 7.70 
    if (regex(ip)==True): ##If ip is valid
        try:
            nm = nmap.PortScanner() 
            result_1 = nm.scan(ip,arguments="-p 1-65535 -T5") #Just for test

            output = ({"Name":result_1["scan"][ip]["tcp"]})
            # print(output)
            return output #It will return with the output that needed

        except KeyError: 
            return None
```

Comment: are you sure that functions are the same? how do you check the runtime in 2 cases?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same functions. Flower is a monitoring tool for celery tasks so I used them to check runtime.

Comment: As I said, the problem usage of cpu power. Celery use just %2-3 cpu power but without celery approx. %90

Comment: what type of celery execution pool do you use?

Comment: I didn't speficy a pool, it is default. (Prefork)

Comment: @fatihcelik Just little bit explanations about **how do you check the runtime in 2 cases?** How you run `function`? Just on a host / in the same machine with `celery`? How you run celery(just on host / inside container etc)?

Comment: Both of them are running on Ubuntu 18.04 Virtualbox. I check celery runtime with flower monitoring tool and the other just a looking at seconds because it is very fast without celery :)

Comment: Celery, with prefork concurrency, runs task exactly the same way you run it as standalone Python script. Since we can't look at the task it is next to impossible to tell you what the problem is.

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: @fatihcelik well I recommend to add logs for debugging. before `if (regex(ip)==True)`. `logger.info('task started')`, before `nm.scan`, after etc. You'll find the place of delay.

Comment: Are you trying to say that if you just call (on the same machine!) `port_scan(ip)` in a Python shell it runs 5-10s, and if you let Celery run the task (by calling `.delay()` or `.apply_async()`) it runs for 15m? Could it be something as simple as - you did not have available workers so it took some time for some of them to become idle?

Comment: I create a test environment so this is the only task on the queue. I mean, worker is already available for a task. When I call the task, it's status changed immediately to 'Started'.

Comment: @fatihcelik what does the log say?

Comment: I think, the problem is about nmap. This is very interesting.

Comment: And let me guess - this "test environment" is completely different than the place where the function takes 5-10 s to complete? `nmap -T5` (highest concurrency) will run much faster on machine with many cores, than on machine with one core.

Comment: No. Programs run different privilege levels, nmap takes a long time if it works with sudo privilege because apply syn scan. If nmap runs with normal user privilege, applies tcp connect scan so this isn't take a long time.